# Update one sprite among a group of sprites [Pygame]

Tags: python, pygame

First post here. So I am trying to implement a Civilization type of movement game. At the moment, I have one sprite in a cell. I can click it and then if I click another grid, the sprite moves there. What I now want is to spawn 5-6 such sprites, and then do the same thing. Click on a sprite and then click another grid, and that specific sprite moves there without affecting the other sprites. I cannot seem to do that. I can spawn 5-6 random sprites at different grids, but when I click on one of them and then click another grid, all the other sprites are gone. The code is below (not the best as I am learning Pygame). I understand that I have to somehow only update the sprite that was clicked, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 700
FPS = 2


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

TURN = "TeamOne"

def main():
    # Pygame sprite Example

    global x_lines
    global y_lines
    x_lines = [WIDTH-i*WIDTH/20 for i in range(20,0, -1)]
    y_lines = [HEIGHT-j*HEIGHT/20 for j in range(20,0, -1)]


    class TeamOne(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        # sprite for the Player
        def __init__(self):
            # this line is required to properly create the sprite
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            # create a plain rectangle for the sprite image
            self.image = pygame.Surface((WIDTH / 20, HEIGHT / 20))
            self.image.fill(GREEN)
            # find the rectangle that encloses the image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            # center the sprite on the screen
            self.rect.center = ((random.randint(1,19)*2+1)* WIDTH/ 40, (random.randint(1,19)*2+1)*HEIGHT/40)



        def update(self, position):
            # any code here will happen every time the game loop updates
            (a, b) = position
            for index, i in enumerate(x_lines):
                if i > a:
                    self.rect.x = x_lines[index-1]
                    break
            for index, j in enumerate(y_lines):
                if j > b:
                    self.rect.y = y_lines[index-1]
                    break






        # initialize pygame and create window
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("A Game")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clicked_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    teamone_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    for i in range(5):
        mob1 = TeamOne()
        teamone_sprites.add(mob1)



    # Game loop
    running = True
    j=0
    while running:
        # keep loop running at the right speed
        clock.tick(FPS)
        # Process input (events)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # check for closing window
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and j == 0:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                for s in teamone_sprites:
                    if s.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                        #teamone_sprites.add(s)
                        clicked_sprites.add(s)
                        print (clicked_sprites)
                        j = 1
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and j == 1:
                new_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                #teamone_sprites.update(new_pos)
                clicked_sprites.update(new_pos)
                j = 0



            # Update





                        # Draw / render
##                screen.fill(BLACK)
##                draw_grid(screen)
##
##                teamone_sprites.draw(screen)
##
##
##
##                # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
##                pygame.display.flip()
                                # Draw / render
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        draw_grid(screen)

        teamone_sprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()






    pygame.quit()


def draw_grid(screen):
    for i in range(1, HEIGHT, int(HEIGHT/20)):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, (1,i) ,(WIDTH,i), 2)

    for j in range(1, WIDTH, int(WIDTH/20)):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, (j,1) ,(j,HEIGHT), 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Some tips for you:

- Keep your main loop clean
- Put logic where it belongs
- Only call `pygame.display.flip()`/`pygame.display.update()` once
- Don't use variable names like `j`
- Since your game is grid based, you should have a way to translate between grid coordinates and screen coordinates

Here's a simple runnable example I hacked together (see the comments for some explanations):

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 700
ROWS = 20
COLUMNS = 20
TILE_SIZE = WIDTH / COLUMNS, HEIGHT / ROWS
TILE_W, TILE_H = TILE_SIZE
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

TURN = "TeamOne"

# some functions to translate grid <-> screen coordinates
def posToScreen(pos):
    column, row = pos
    return column * TILE_W, row * TILE_H

def screenToPos(pos):
    column, row = pos
    return column / TILE_W, row / TILE_H    

def draw_grid(screen):
    for i in range(1, HEIGHT, TILE_H):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, (1,i) ,(WIDTH,i), 2)

    for j in range(1, WIDTH, TILE_W):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, (j,1) ,(j,HEIGHT), 2)

# a class that handles selecting units
class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, units, *groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *groups)

        # group of the units that can be controlled
        self.units = units

        # we create two images
        # to indicate if we are selecting or moving
        self.image = pygame.Surface(TILE_SIZE)
        self.image.set_colorkey((43,43,43))
        self.image.fill((43,43,43))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.selected_image = self.image.copy()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, pygame.Color('red'), self.image.get_rect(), 4)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.selected_image, pygame.Color('purple'), self.image.get_rect(), 4)
        self.base_image = self.image

        self.selected = None

    def update(self):
        # let's draw the rect on the grid, based on the mouse position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.topleft = posToScreen(screenToPos(pos))

    def handle_click(self, pos):
        if not self.selected:
            # if we have not selected a unit, do it now
            for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.units, False):
                self.selected = s
                self.image = self.selected_image
        else:
            # if we have a unit selected, just set its target attribute, so it will move on its own
            self.selected.target = posToScreen(screenToPos(pos))
            self.image = self.base_image
            self.selected = None

class TeamOne(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(TILE_SIZE)
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.pos = random.randint(0, COLUMNS), random.randint(0, ROWS)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = posToScreen(self.pos))
        self.target = None

    def update(self):
        # do nothing until target is set
        # (maybe unset it if we reached our target)
        if self.target:
            if self.rect.x < self.target[0]:
                self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
            elif self.rect.x > self.target[0]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
            elif self.rect.y < self.target[1]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
            elif self.rect.y > self.target[1]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        self.pos = screenToPos(self.rect.topleft)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("A Game")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    team_ones = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for i in range(5):
        TeamOne(all_sprites, team_ones)
    cursor = Cursor(team_ones, all_sprites)

    # a nice, simple, clean main loop
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            # we could also pass all events to all sprites
            # so we would not need this special clause for the cursor...
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                cursor.handle_click(event.pos)

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        draw_grid(screen)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!!! That is more than what I expected. Thank you very much. I will study your code to understand it better. Any chance you could look at my code above and let me know what am i missing. I would really love to see what am I missing and I believe it could be something to do with a built in sprite command.

Comment: @konjecture If you want to only move one sprite, there's no reason for you to use a group here (`clicked_sprites`). But, the problem in your code is that you keep adding sprites to `clicked_sprites`, and never remove them from this group. An easy fix would be to simply call `clicked_sprites.empty()` after `clicked_sprites.update(new_pos)`. But keep in mind that `update` is usually called every frame, not just on a mouse click.

Answer (score -1):

I have pretty much the same Problem i have a healthbar for my enemie but i want all enemys to have one so its a spritegroup now if i want to change an attribute of one object out of my spritegroup i dont know how to properly access it. The Problem lays in the Healthbaranimation function. I tried self.healthbar.sprites()  self.healthbar.sprites and spritedict nothing really semms to work. Is there an easy way to fix this? P.s sorry for my bad code It is my first real attempt making a small game

```
from os import path

import pygame

from elements.ammo import AMMO
from elements.bigenemy import BIGENEMY
from elements.enemy import ENEMY
from elements.player import PLAYER
from .base import BaseState
from elements.healthbar import HEALTHBAR




class Gameplay(BaseState):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gameplay, self).__init__()
        self.next_state = "GAME_OVER"
        self.x, self.y = 100, 1030
        self.playersprite = PLAYER((self.x, self.y))
        self.bigenemy = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(BIGENEMY())
        self.bottomrect = pygame.Rect((0, 1030), (1920, 50))
        self.enemysprite = ENEMY()
        self.ammosprite = AMMO()
        self.healthbar = pygame.sprite.Group(HEALTHBAR())
        self.displayedimage = self.playersprite.image
        self.displayedrect = self.playersprite.rect
        self.highscore = self.load_data()
        self.points = 0
        self.scoretext = f"SCORE: {self.points}"
        self.scoresurf = self.font.render(self.scoretext, True, "red")
        self.nhstext = "NEW HIGHSCORE!"
        self.nhssurf = self.font.render(self.nhstext, True, "red")
        self.ammotext = f"AMMO:{self.playersprite.ammunition}"
        self.ammosurf = self.font.render(self.ammotext, True, "red")
        self.bulletgroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.time_active = 0
        self.bigenemyexisting = True

    def get_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.quit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
                self.playersprite.crouching = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.playersprite.jumping = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q and self.playersprite.ammunition != 0:
                self.playersprite.shooting = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.done = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
                self.playersprite.crouching = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                self.playersprite.shooting = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, "red", self.bottomrect)
        surface.blit(self.displayedimage, (self.displayedrect))
        surface.blit(self.enemysprite.image, (self.enemysprite.rect))
        surface.blit(self.ammosprite.image, (self.ammosprite.rect))
        self.healthbar.draw(surface)
        self.bigenemy.draw(surface)
        self.bulletgroup.draw(surface)
        surface.blit(self.scoresurf, (0, 0))
        surface.blit(self.ammosurf, (0, 1000))
        if self.points > self.highscore: surface.blit(self.nhssurf, (1920 / 2 - 100, 1080 / 2))

    def lost(self):
        self.enemysprite.startposx = 1920
        self.enemysprite.startposy = self.enemysprite.gettypeenemy()
        self.enemysprite.speed = 10
        self.highscorefunc()
        self.points = 0
        self.playersprite.ammunition = 30

    def collidecheck(self):
        self.playermask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.displayedimage)
        self.enemymask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.enemysprite.image)

        offsetx = self.enemysprite.rect.left - self.displayedrect.left
        offsety = self.enemysprite.rect.top - self.displayedrect.top
        if self.displayedrect.colliderect(self.enemysprite.rect):
            if self.playermask.overlap(self.enemymask, (offsetx, offsety)):
                self.lost()
                self.done = True
        elif self.enemysprite.rect.x < 0 and self.enemysprite.speed < 25:
            self.points += 1
            self.enemysprite.speed += 1
        elif self.enemysprite.speed > 25:
            self.enemysprite.speed += .5
        elif self.displayedrect.colliderect(self.ammosprite.rect):
            self.ammosprite.startposx = 2300
            self.playersprite.ammunition += 30
        elif  pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bigenemy,self.bulletgroup,False,True):
            self.bigenemy.sprite.health -= 10

    def shooting(self, dt):
        if self.playersprite.ammunition != 0:
            if self.playersprite.shooting and not self.playersprite.jumping and not self.playersprite.crouching:
                self.time_active += dt
                if self.time_active >= 100:
                    self.bulletgroup.add(self.playersprite.createbullet())
                    self.time_active = 0
                    self.playersprite.ammunition -= 1
        else:
            self.playersprite.shooting = False

    def highscorefunc(self):
        if self.points > self.highscore:
            self.highscore = self.points
            with open(path.join(self.dir, self.HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(self.highscore))

    def animation(self):
        if not self.playersprite.shooting and not self.playersprite.jumping and not self.playersprite.crouching:
            if self.playersprite.index >= len(self.playersprite.basicanimation):
                self.playersprite.index = 0
            self.displayedimage = self.playersprite.basicanimation[int(self.playersprite.index)]
            self.playersprite.index += .1
        elif self.playersprite.shooting and not self.playersprite.jumping:
            if self.playersprite.index >= len(self.playersprite.shootanimation):
                self.playersprite.index = 0
            self.displayedimage = self.playersprite.shootanimation[int(self.playersprite.index)]
            self.playersprite.index += .1
        elif self.playersprite.jumping:
            self.displayedimage = self.playersprite.imagejump
        elif self.playersprite.crouching:
            self.displayedimage = self.playersprite.slidingimage

    def healthbaranimation(self):
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 90:
            self.healthbar.spritedict.index = 1
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 80:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 2
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 70:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 3
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 60:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 4
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 50:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 5
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 40:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 6
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 30:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 7
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 20:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 8
        if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 10:
            self.healthbar.sprite.index = 9

    def spawnbigenemies(self):
        if self.bigenemyexisting:
            if self.bigenemy.sprite.health < 3:
                self.bigenemy.add(BIGENEMY())
                self.bigenemyexisting = True

    def update(self, dt):
        try:
            self.bigenemy.sprite.update()
        except:
            pass
        self.healthbaranimation()
        self.healthbar.update()
        self.playersprite.jump()
        self.animation()
        self.shooting(dt)
        self.bulletgroup.update()
        self.enemysprite.update()
        self.ammosprite.update()
        self.collidecheck()
        self.spawnbigenemies()
        self.scoretext = f"SCORE: {self.points}"
        self.scoresurf = self.font.render(self.scoretext, True, "black")
        self.ammotext = f"AMMO:{self.playersprite.ammunition}"
        self.ammosurf = self.font.render(self.ammotext, True, "red")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30839005)